# access hash member of type array within array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array of anonymous hashes like this:

```
my @arrayOfHashes=(
    {
        name => 'foo',
        value => ['one', 'two']
    },
    {
        name => 'bar',
        value => ['two', 'three']
    }
);
```

I'm trying to iterate over the array and access the array within each hash:

```
foreach (@arrayOfHashes) {
    print $_->{'value'} # ARRAY(0x88489f4)
}
```

The value that is printed above is not what I want... I want to use that array so it works like this:

```
print qw(one two) # onetwo
```

But, when I use *qw* like this:

```
my @arrayOfHashes=(
    {
        name => 'foo',
        qw(one two)
    },
    {
        name => 'bar',
        qw(three four)
    }
);
```

I get this error message at runtime (I am using strict mode):

```
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at ...
```

How do I reference the "value" array within the *foreach* block?

Comment: `@{$_->{'value'}}`.. the error message should not occur.. since there is an even number of elements in the hashes.. for example (`name`, `'foo'`, `"one"`, `"two"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have a reference to an array you want to dereference. The equivalent of `@array` for when you have a reference is `@{ $ref }`, so

```
print("@array\n");

print(join(', ', @array), "\n");
```

would be

```
print("@{ $_->{value} }\n");

print(join(', ', @{ $_->{value} }), "\n");
```

References:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)