# accessing parsed json data in perl

Tags: json, perl

I have the following json data in a string `$json`:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 37.4224764,
                "lng": -122.0842499
            },
        },
    }]
}
```

I use the following to decode my JSON data.

```
my $decoded_json = decode_json( $json );
```

And I'm attempting at retrieving the latitude here:

```
my $lat=$decoded_json->{results}->{geometry}{location}{lat};
```

And Here:

```
my $lat=$decoded_json->{results}->{geometry}->{location}->{lat};
```

I'd like to know how to retrieve the `lat` and `lng` from this decoded data.

Comment: Once you decode your JSON document, you now have a [Perl data structure](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). The fact that the contents of that structure were constructed by parsing a JSON document are completely irrelevant to what you do with it.

Comment: There's an array in your JSON, but no array dereference in your code...

Comment: @ikegami i dont know anything about perl datastructures. im fairly new. can you modify my access code to perform correctly?

Comment: `$ref->[$idx]`. See the list of references found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31685348/589924).

Comment: @ikegami can you make an answer showing me the correct code to use. like i said im fairly new

Comment: @SinanÜnür I understand that already. My issue is I dont have experience with perl data structures. can you help me by fixing my code that uses the datastructure to perform correctly.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Id appreciate some help on this. Im having difficulty figuring this out. I looked on the sites and i am lost as to how to resolve this.

Comment: @ikegami I am completely lost as to how to resolve this. I dont really understand anything about perl datastructures and trying to understand has got me nowhere from your link. can you please assist with a code sample so i can look at understand

Comment: @ikegami I tried now unsuccessfully:  `my $lat = $decoded_json->[results]->{geometry}->{location}->{lat};`

Comment: `$decoded_json` was produced from `{ "results": ... }`, so it's a reference to a hash, not a reference to an array.

Comment: @ikegami if you could modify my code from the last comment to show me how to access the latitude value inside the data i gave you i would be very appreciative. im trying to understand perl datastructures and its becoming very difficult. can you please just show me how to access this data?

Comment: What does `$decoded_json->{results}` return?

Comment: @ikegami  cannot see the contents but it says array when i debug print

Comment: Right. It's a reference to array produced from `[ ... ]` in the JSON. How many elements are in that array (from looking at the JSON, for example)?

Comment: Here's an example of a full response: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA    im looking specifically for the geometry section

Comment: (Hashes and arrays can only contain scalars, so we can't store hashes and arrays in hashes and arrays. We can, however, store *references* to then.)

Comment: That won't do. I'm not asking these questions for the answer. I know the answer. I want you to find the answer. How many elements in the array in your question? Just look at the JSON at count.

Comment: @ikegami i see 5 elements inside the results array - address_components, formatted_address, geometry,place_id,types

Comment: No, Those are keys of various hashes (or "objects", as they called in JSON). `[ ... ]` is an array in JSON. How many things are (directly) in `[ ... ]`?

Comment: @ikegami i see one hash inside the [ ], and then inside that hash are the various hashes

Comment: Correct. So you want the first element of the array. Since arrays use 0-based indexes in Perl, that means index `0`. I shall answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an array in your JSON, but no array dereference in your code. In other words, you completely overlooked the `[ ... ]` in the JSON. You need to specify which of the results you want. In the example in question, there is only one, so you could use the following:

```
my $loc = $decoded_json->{results}[0]{geometry}{location};
my $lat = $loc->{lat}; 
my $lng = $loc->{lng};
```

Of course, the whole point of using an array of results is that the number of results might vary. You will probably need a loop.

```
for my $result (@{ $decoded_json->{results} }){
   my $loc = $result->{geometry}{location};
   my $lat = $loc->{lat}; 
   my $lng = $loc->{lng}; 
   ...
}
```

---

About the arrows...

```
my $lat = $decoded_json->{results}[0]{geometry}{location}{lat};
```

is short for

```
my $lat = $decoded_json->{results}->[0]->{geometry}->{location}->{lat};
```

When the `->` is between `{...}` or `[...]`, and `{...}` or `[...]`, it can be omitted.

That's why there's no difference between

```
$result->{geometry}{location}{lat};
```

```
$result->{geometry}{location}->{lat};
```

```
( $result->{geometry}{location} )->{lat};   # Can't be omitted here.
```

```
my $loc = $result->{geometry}{location};
my $lat = $loc->{lat};                      # Can't be omitted here.
```

Comment: ok so i needed to define the 0 index placement. i see. i got real confused by the syntax and it troubled me. thanks for the help

Comment: You have `{[{{{` in the JSON, so you basically have to have that in Perl too.

Answer (score 1):

Given the name of the key, "result**s**", it is natural to expect there might be times where you get more than one result. The following will give you the coordinates for all results returned:

```
for my $r (@{ $decoded_json->{results} }) {
    my ($lat, $lng) = @{ $r->{geometry}{location} }{qw(lat lng)}
    # do something with coordinates
}
```

With recent Perl versions, you can re-write that as:

```
for my $r ($decoded_json->{results}->@*) {
    my ($lat, $lng) = $r->{geometry}{location}->@{qw(lat lng)};
    # do something with coordinates
}
```

Once again, `decode_json` gives you a [Perl data structure](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). The fact that the contents of that structure were constructed by parsing a JSON document are completely irrelevant to what you do with it.

Working example ([Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS) chokes on your JSON):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::MaybeXS qw( decode_json );

my $json_string = <<EO_JSON;
{
    "results": [{
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 37.4224764,
                "lng": -122.0842499
                }
         }
    }]
}
EO_JSON

my $data = decode_json($json_string);

for my $r (@{ $data->{results} }) {
    my ($lat, $lng) = @{ $r->{geometry}{location} }{qw(lat lng)};
    print "($lat,$lng)\n";
}

for my $r ($data->{results}->@*) {
    my ($lat, $lng) = $r->{geometry}{location}->@{qw(lat lng)};
    print "($lat,$lng)\n";
}
```